# How Can I Retrieve hass or comma separated value from database using codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am Involve a CodeIgniter Project.In this project another developer insert cat_id in the database include # separated like #1#. when insert two cat_id the value store in database like #1##2#.

Now I want to retrieve the cat_id and join it to the another table.

Comment: Are you understand my problem ?

Comment: I want to  retrieve 1 and 2 form #1##2# . I don't change the database or insert code

Comment: "I want to retrieve 1 and 2 form #1##2# . I don't change the database or insert code" Converting your code and database to support normalization is alot faster then you trying to figure this one out, trust me you don't to got in the direction off using extra code to parse out the cat_id from #1##2#

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've made a mistake in my first attempt (find bellow), this hopfully this should work:

```
$text = "#1##2##10000";
$ids = array_filter(explode('#', $text));

// output
array(3) { [1]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "2" [5]=> string(5) "10000" }
```

Bonus if you want to reset the array keys to start from 0 again:

```
$ids = array_values(array_filter(explode('#', $text)));

// output
array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(5) "10000" }
```

Old incorrect answer:

```
$text = "#1##2#";

$ids = [];
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($text); $i++) { 
    if ($text[$i] != '#') {
        $ids[] = $text[$i];
    }
}

var_dump($ids);
// produced result
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" }
```

Comment: hi, it return blank

Comment: Hi, are you sure that the $text variable is not empty or something, I've just tested the code locally, and it works like a charm. I've added my output to the answer.

Comment: "it works like a charm." test it with `$text = "#1##2##10000";` ...

Comment: @RaymondNijland I just did, this is the output: array(7) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "0" [4]=> string(1) "0" [5]=> string(1) "0" [6]=> string(1) "0" }, that seems ok to me

Comment: hmm no...`10000` is one number in that string right?

Comment: Lol yea you are right, sorry.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for pointing out my mistake, I've edited my answer and it should be correct now, also I think that the new solution is more concise and elegant than the old one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
$str = "#1##2#";
preg_match_all('|\d+|',$str,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Here is working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dfe865fcdea4e688b1deb5e55e1bec3e983956db).

Comment: The general way would be to init the `$matches` array `$matches = array(); $matches = []; (PHP5-7)` first before using `preg_match_all(...)` to avoid warnings and possible flowcontrol bugs later in the code about missing  the `$matches` variable

Comment: Please show me that error reporting level in PHP where it will throw warning/notice for undefined variable for matches. `By Documentation of preg_match_all`. As per my knowledge, `$matches` is getting defined there.

Comment: "As per my knowledge, $matches is getting defined there." Now i indeed look better it's `&$matches` which is a reference so it will not generate missing warnings.. Ok i will give you a other reason (less important) then missing out possible IDE code auto completion support on the `$matches` variable.. Also the general sense would be to init the variable always also when the variable is autoset by a reference like in this case then you follow good programming habits in mine opion.

Comment: Okay @RaymondNijland I will keep a note of it. I always stick to basics, `E_ALL` is always active while I do code. Thanks.

Comment: what about the $matches @RahulMeshram

Answer (score -1):

> I want to retrieve 1 and 2 form #1##2# . I don't change the database
>   or insert code

I strongly suggest you into changing your PHP code and MySQL tables into supporting normalisation. 
Because the needed query to fetch ("parse") a cat_id number from `#1##2#` is a total nightmare and will not perform well. 
The query looks more or less like this without the extra join to a other table.

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT
   REVERSE(
      REVERSE(
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(<table>.<column>, '##', rows.row), '##', -1) 
   ) >> 1 ) AS cat_id
FROM (
  SELECT 
   @row := @row + 1 AS ROW
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row1
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
  ) row2  
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT @row := 0 
  ) init_user_params
)
 ROWS
CROSS JOIN 
 <table>
```

But then i feel the next question coming.

> How can i convert that SQL into codeignitor's code?

So now a PHP example to parse out cat_ids

**PHP code**

```
<?php
  $text = "#1##2##10000";

  $cat_ids = explode("##", trim($text, '#'));

  var_dump($cat_ids);
?>
```

**Result**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "10000"
}
```

Comment: A mobile application is running using the database. So I can't any change this DB.
And yes it hard from me. and you are  right about my next question.

Comment: "A mobile application is running using the database" @MinhazurRahaman I assume after hearing that you didn't build in a application version checker which blocks and forces the user into downloading a mobile application update?

Comment: "And yes it hard from me. and you are right about my next question" If mine SQL code works you should only have cat_id's you still have to make a join..  Codeignitor supports `$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');` [manual](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html) to direct query access keep in mind the SQL in there can have SQL injections when user input is used so you need to use `$this->db->escape(..)` to protect those.. This is the most easy method.